# $(this).next('div') not grabbing the content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip, qtip2

I am using **jQuery 1.11.1** and **qTip 2.2.2** and this js code to grab the content of my hidden div element for qTip:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('.hasTooltip').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $(this).next('div') 
            }
        });
    });

});
```

And the html is:

```
<div class="hasTooltip">Hover me to see a tooltip</div>
<div class="hidden">This is just a test!</div>
```

But it's not working, meaning the yellow qtip bubble shows up on hover, but there is no text at all. However, if I try it put there manualy like this:

```
content: {
    text: "Test!"
}
```

Then the tooltip shows like expected.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**SOLVED 
+
REQUEST @qTtip developers**

Dear qTip developers,

Please add the `.html()` to the end of `$(this).next('div')` like this `$(this).next('div').html()`. Currently your default solution without the `.html()` was not working for me. Thank you. *Additional info I am using Bootstrap 3 and Laravel 4 together with qTip.*

Comment: try `text: $(this).next('div').html()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Why did you deleted your answer? Please, put it back for others. Thank you.

Comment: but your code seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mFQks/2/

Comment: Hmm, I see. But in my project it's not working like in the jsfiddle example and the code is the same. I am using Bootstrap 3 together with qTip, so maybe there is some conflict. Anyway, if I attach `.html()` to the `$(this).next('div')` then `$(this).next('div').html()` will grab the content as expected. Btw. I am using Laravel 4, but I don't think it has something to do with that.

Comment: as per the [doc](http://qtip2.com/options#content.text) it should be fine `content.text: Deferred, function(){}, jQuery([ ]), "String", true (Default: true)`

Comment: Since it works in the fiddle the way the documentation says, something in your application must be conflicting. Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because `text` property does not accept a jQuery object so try to pass the contents of the `div` as its value

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.hasTooltip').each(function () {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $(this).next('div').html()
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: This helped and qTip shows the text ;D. Any idea, why the qTip developers didn't have .html() in the docs? I was just following their tutorial here: http://qtip2.com/guides#content.element

Comment: Making `content.text` only work with a string is more versatile. I could have a translation object full of strings for example. Using `.html()` internally would break for anything that isn't a jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 text: $(this).next('div').text()
```

Comment: Thank you, this will show the text, however, it will also strip all the links etc. so it's better to use `html()` instead of `text()` in my case.